# CSS Framework - off the shelf or homegrown?

Tags: html, css, frameworks, frontend

Is there an existing framework that satisfies the needs of your projects with minor modifications, or have you developed your own along the way? What do you recommend for someone trying to make that decision with these priorities:

1. CSS reset
2. Attention to typography; baseline grid
3. Semantic classes
4. Accessibility
5. Lots of "Helper" classes: e.g. .demphasized, .errormsg, .readmore etc.
6. Grid system, unless it conflicts with #3

Not a priority: 
 - Fluid/Elastic layout support
 - Type in ems/%s

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a lot of dup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670156/

Comment: Thanks, I did a search before I posted but didn't see that. Lots of helpful information there.

Answer (score 2):

No framework out there is going to do everything you want.

But [Blueprint](http://code.google.com/p/blueprintcss/) should have enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get pretty far with these:

[960 Grid for layouts](http://960.gs/)

[Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/)

[The jQuery UI CSS Framework](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API#The_jQuery_UI_CSS_Framework)

[YAML](http://www.yaml.de/en/)

Answer (score 0):

Elastic css framework can do it almost all you want, except baseline (yet) but you can integrate it including your baseline.css, got to elasticss.com.

No cryptic classnames, support for combinig classes, centering x and y, same height, seo friendly (support for templates and adaptive layouts)

lots of helper classes, and definetely non intrusive with your classes, or absolute positioning. all for free and for all browsers :) hope you like it.

and yes it supports fixed, fluid, elastic layouts, and you just can combine them to get advanced stuff, you also get unlimited nesting, so elastic wont let you down after first level

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [Siimpler](http://siimpler.com/) it's a simple html framework with ready made file/folder structure but your can configure it for you needs. For exp. you can choose between CSS reset and Normalize.css.